# Postdoc Mentor wants me to leave

Tags: postdocs

I recently finished my PhD and work as a Research Tech for a bit. At that time, i got two postdoc offers. I joined the one which gave me my own postdoc funding for two years. I worked there for 9 months. I was given another offer from another university. They mentioned about the quality of research and how lab is well funded. I gave away my funding to join this new position. within first three months, I realized that this was a big mistake because of the work environment. In the first week of the appointment, i asked him if we should buy the multichannel pipette to reduce the pipetting errors. His old postdoc jumped in and said "We never used that in past and he is saying just because of lot of work". At another occasion she said "If you want to work here you need to ask people before doing anything" 
My mentor is obsessed with her. when i tried to discuss with him he said if this is not the place for me, i have to find other lab. I have been continuously doubted and humiliated in lab meetings. They criticize that my PhD training is below the level of a masters student. I am really concerned where my career is going to move. I cant even apply for other jobs as i switched two labs in last two years. I would appreciate if i can get any guidance in this forum. I am really really scared and feel like my career is finished.

Comment: Who is "he" and who is "she" in your story?

Comment: "I gave away my funding to join this new position." Why? It seems like you are omitting relevant information. Who leaves a funded position just because someone "mentioned about the quality of research and how lab is well funded"? Also, "I cant even apply for other jobs as i switched two labs in last two years." is objectively not true. Your chances might be lower and you might even have to look outside of Academia, but you have options.